# How do i achieve Wordpress to moodle SSO

Tags: wordpress, single-sign-on, moodle

I would like to achieve wordpress to moodle sso. If a user logs into wordpress i want the user to also be automatically logged into moodle.

I have already intergrated the courses from moodle into wordpress.

Any ideas on how to achieve this, i would rather not use plugins. Any leads will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to be better off using a plugin. As you will need to use wordpress Oauth to authenticate a moodle user againist your wordpress database.

So in short If a user logs into moodle their password will be stored and authenticated in wordpress.

This tutorial on moodle explains how best to handle it in the most efficient way.

https://moodle.org/plugins/auth_wordpress

Comment: i appreciate this but i would like to use a custom script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugin MooWoodle Pro (https://dualcube.com/product/moowoodle-pro/), that support SSO between wordpress and moodle.